# How to prevent food absorbing smells from other food?

Tags: baking

I want to bake cakes to take into work tomorrow. But I also have a broccoli and half an onion that need eating soon, and was thinking of having broccoli and sausages with onion for dinner. Is there a way of baking the cakes and cooking the dinner on the same evening without the cakes absorbing broccoli/ onion smell, or do these activities need to be done on different days? Which is it better to cook first?

Possibly relevant information about this specific situation (though I think more general answers would be better):

- There is an extractor fan which can be used if necessary (though it's very noisy and annoying).
- The cakes would be cupcakes/butterfly buns with buttercream.
- I prefer to do the sausages and onions in the oven rather than the frying pan, but don't have to.

Comment: Is this really an issue you have? I have never had this be a problem in the past.

Comment: Cake first, then stow it in an airtight container.  The smells only come into play if they are already there, I'd think.

Comment: Cook your meal and don't worry about smell transfers. Unless you have your onion and cake in the oven at the same time it's a non-issue. Even then it's probably not a problem.

Comment: Of all the ultra-imaginative, hypothetical and arcane topics people bring up here that nobody questions, you doubt that this particular one is a real isssue? What about it seems fantastical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To people saying it's not an issue... um.. yes it bloody is! If I cook a smelly oniony meal in the oven and then bake cake or something in it (even the next) it absolutely absorbs smells and really ruins it!

Comment: It's possible that your response is going to get turned into a comment, but you've effectively answered the question -- don't cook the onion-y item before the cake.  (And it's even worse to bake them together.  You want to bake the cake *before* the other dish).  For people who say it's not a problem, maybe it's not for you -- some people are more sensitive to flavors and smells, and some onions are more pungent than others.  You *can* vent the oven for a while in between, but then you're wasting heat / gas / electricity / whatever.

Comment: As Joe suggested, this needs an [edit] to be a proper answer. You can remove the opinions as well.